# How to connect laravel with powermta using phpmailer or swiftmailer?

Tags: laravel, phpmailer, swiftmailer, postfix-mta

I need the code sample for connect powermta with laravel php using swiftmailer or phpmailer anybody help me

Comment: It helps a lot if you would show us what you've tried so far. This is a Q&A platform afterall.

Comment: Via SMTP, just as the many examples show.

Comment: Thank you mr. @ Eduard and mr. @Synchro  i know how to use swiftmailer with smtp but i'm new to powermta . so i need suggestion from experienced people is there possible for ip rotation . I have my own dedicated server with 5 ips need to send each mail from different ip for preventing from ddo attack .

Comment: As far as I’m aware PowerMTA has an SMTP interface like any other mail server. It may also have an HTTP interface, but most mail classes won’t handle that. If you want it to rotate source IP, you could either rotate via DNS, or if PMTA has the ability to control that specifically, set whatever headers it needs to control that - refer to their docs rather than asking here. I would also note that multiple IPs on the same server does not provide any protection against DDoS attacks.